# Change count to for_each Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, hcl

How to change this line into for_each? I want to get resource ID of azurerm_network_connection_monitor. All these resources are iterated through for_each.

```
azurerm_network_connection_monitor.monitor[element(keys(var.names), count.index)].id
```

**Modules**

```
resource "azurerm_network_connection_monitor" "monitor" {
  for_each             = var.names
  name                 = each.value.name
  network_watcher_name = var.network_watcher_name
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  location             = var.location

  interval_in_seconds = each.value.interval_in_seconds

  source {
    virtual_machine_id = each.value.virtual_machine_id
    port               = var.source_port
  }

  destination {
    port    = each.value.port
    address = each.value.address
  }

  tags = var.tags
  }
}



resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "rtt_alert" {
  depends_on = [azurerm_network_connection_monitor.monitor]

  for_each            = var.rtt_criteria
  name                = "HPG-ALRT-${lookup(azurerm_network_connection_monitor.monitor, each.value["name"], null)}-001-${each.value.name}"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  scopes              = [azurerm_network_connection_monitor.monitor[element(keys(var.names), count.index)].id]
  enabled             = each.value.enabled
  auto_mitigate       = var.auto_mitigate
  description         = each.value.description
  frequency           = each.value.frequency
  severity            = each.value.severity
  window_size         = each.value.window_size

  dynamic_criteria {
    metric_namespace         = each.value.metric_namespace
    metric_name              = each.value.metric_name
    aggregation              = each.value.aggregation
    operator                 = each.value.operator
    alert_sensitivity        = each.value.alert_sensitivity
    evaluation_total_count   = each.value.evaluation_total_count
    evaluation_failure_count = each.value.evaluation_failure_count
  }

  action {
    action_group_id = var.action_group_id
  }

  tags = var.tags
}
```

I don't know how to get ID of each index of azurerm_network_connection_monitor.monitor.

Answer (score 0):

The resource `azurerm_network_connection_monitor` includes a `for_each` argument whose value is a map or a set of strings, Terraform will create one instance for each member of that map or set.

You could use the [values](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/values.html) function to take the map and returns a list containing the values of the elements in that map.

You could try to set it like this:

```
scopes              = [values(azurerm_network_connection_monitor.monitor)[*].id]
```

A similar test result

[image]

Comment: It could probably work with `scopes = [values(azurerm_network_connection_monitor.monitor)[0].id]` but I want to get each id for each alert.

Comment: How do you define the `var.names` and `var.rtt_criteria`?

Comment: var.names and var.rtt_criteria are map(object) type.

`variable "names" { type = map(object({})) }`

Comment: There is a separate `for_each` for the different resource monitor and different resource alert. It's not possible to get each monitor id for each alert in a separate loop unless you are using a local expression to construct the monitor result and pass it into the alert loop. Or you can re-generate a common variable to use it in both resources. Not sure but I will have a try.

Answer (score 0):

I actually get an error:
[image]

because I want to use id in metric alert scope